# How to check Processor Generation?

Tags: linux, cpu

I was trying to exchange my laptop in an online site and i need to provide them my processor generation. They have shown how to check that in windows machine but i'm using a linux machine. How to check my processor generation in linux?

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you for your replay i tried the command but i got confused with output listing, can you say which name is reffering to the processor generation.

Comment: Edit your question and post it here.

Comment: Is `sudo dmidecode -s processor-family` what you are looking for?

Comment: dmidecode gives the family, not the generation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find using this command below

> lscpu | grep "Model name"

it will show your exact CPU model number, for intel desktop processor the generation shown by processor number,

> Intel Core i5-5300U this is the fifth generation,

or you can search using this link

[ark intel search processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/search.html)

Answer (score 2):

This can be very confusing for Intel. The answer is it depends. For laptops @Iyus Dedi Putra's answer is correct. In the general case this is how you figure it out:

Is it a laptop or a server?

If it is a laptop then as Iyus Dedi Putra mentioned, you can look at that first number. This is explained in depth [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html). To make this more confusing though, the generations also have names. So for example, if you look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon) you'll see a whole bunch of references to named things. Here they have servers and laptop generations mixed together. Each numbered generation also has a corresponding name. Ex: Laptop Gen8 is Coffee Lake UNLESS you are looking at the Xeon series of Coffee Lake processors which are then considered Gen9. So basically the name only kind of sort of matters and is largely arbitrary. It's probably easier to just look at the number but if you do want to figure out the name of the generation there's no way to get this from the OS. You'll have to look it up.

Brain fried yet? We haven't even talked about servers.

If it is a server the answer is it depends... harder. Intel reinvents their processor nomenclature with every new generation of server so deciphering what the numbers mean changes completely with every new named generation. Firstly, how do the names work? Each enterprise processor has a family name. Bridge, Lake, and soon to be released Rapids. Within each of these family names is some sub name. For example, in the Lake series you have Skylake, Cascade Lake, and Ice Lake. This corresponds to the second number in the processor name. For example, I am currently doing work on a Dell R840. My processor name is: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5215 CPU @ 2.50GHz`. The 2 means I have a Cascade Lake, the second in the series.

Still not confusing enough? Wait. There's more.

**In general** each named family has two numbered generations. You'll usually hear this called the "tick" and "tock". For example, Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge. However in the Lake Series they broke that rule and there were three. In Sapphire Rapids they should be going back to it and they'll just have Sapphire Rapids and Graphite Rapids.

Clear as mud? Good

Answer (score 0):

I favor **inxi** as a tool

E.g.

```
inxi -C
```

Which in my case will output

```
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: Intel Xeon E-2286M bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache:
    L2: 2 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3840 min/max: 800/5000 cores: 1: 4557 2: 4527 3: 4584
    4: 4572 5: 4303 6: 4597 7: 3173 8: 4590 9: 800 10: 4379 11: 4470 12: 4304
    13: 4535 14: 800 15: 2700 16: 4564
```

Check the ark as suggested
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192993/intel-xeon-e-2286m-processor-16m-cache-2-40-ghz.html or even better https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/xeon_e/e-2286m.